# Obtaining a parameter using Brent's method

Tags: equation-solving

Using **Brent' method**, I want to find a $g$ which minimizes $\Delta$ that is defined as 
$$\Delta=\sum_{n=1}^N F^2_n \tag{1}$$ where $F_n$ is $$ n(n-1)\mu_{n-1}+2Z\mu+2E\mu_{n+1}-2\alpha\mu_{n+2}-2\beta\mu_{n+3} \tag{2} $$ and $\mu_j$ is defined as $$ \int_0^\infty r^j \Psi(r) dr \tag{3} $$ Suppose we approximate $\Psi$ as $$ e^{- ppa} \tag{4} $$ where $$ppa= \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac {c_n r^n}{(1+g \,r)^{N-3}} \tag{5}$$

Now how can I obtain the best $g$ of equation (5) which minimize $\Delta$ of equation (1)?
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
Ψ[r_] := Exp[-Sum[(c[n] r^n)/(1 + g *r)^p, {n, 1, NN - 1}]];
μ[n_] := NIntegrate[r^n Ψ[r], {r, 0, ∞}];
f[n_] := n (n - 1) μ[n - 1] + 2 z μ[n] + 2 newE μ[n + 1] - 2 α μ[n + 2] -  2 β μ[n + 3];
Δ = Sum[f[n]^2, {n, 1, NN}];
newDD = FindRoot[Δ == 0, {g, 8, 12}, Method -> "Brent"]
```

Any idea?

---

**Addendum**

The quantities for numerical evaluation can be used as follows:
$$\alpha=0$$$$\beta=100$$$$N=8$$$$newE=24.5$$$$z=1$$ and c's

```
{1, 8.5, 33.3333, 95.35, 229.814, 494.7, 970.603}
```

Comment: where are the parameters $\alpha,\beta,Z,E,c_n,N$ defined?

Comment: Assume we have all of them

Comment: I already did assume that. But I want to know their actual values, otherwise one cannot do numerics.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Ok thanks, I added the required quantities

Comment: For that choice of parameters, the function $\Delta=\Delta(g)$ has no roots, so `FindRoot` is not going to find anything. But it does have a minimum (around `g=2.10692`). Do you want a root or a minimum? Your description seems to indicate the latter but your code the former.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform yeah exactly, I need a minimum and g you obtained, is very near to real one, Please explain your procedure in an answer. Also explain what is difference between root and minimum exactly. Thanks again.

Comment: A *root* is a zero. A *minimum* is a minimum; sometimes, a minimum is a root of the *derivative*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
α = 0; β = 100; n = 8; e = 24.5; z = 1; c = {1, 8.5, 33.3333, 95.35, 229.814, 494.7, 970.603};
Clear[Ψ, μ, f, Δ]
Ψ[g_][r_] := Exp[-Sum[(c[[k]] r^k)/(1 + g*r)^(n - 3), {k, 1, n - 1}]];

μ[g_][k_] := NIntegrate[r^k Ψ[g][r], {r, 0, ∞}];

f[g_][k_] := k (k - 1) μ[g][k - 1] + 2 z μ[g][k] + 2 e μ[g][k + 1] - 2 α μ[g][k + 2] - 2 β μ[g][k + 3];
Δ[g_] := Sum[f[g][k]^2, {k, 1, n}];

FindMinimum[{Δ[g], 1.8 < g < 2.4}, {g, 2.1}] // Quiet
(* {0.0104592, {g -> 2.10692}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. several questions: 1-How long this code takes to complete? it is still running for me! 2-where did you specify the Brent's method? 3- How you specify the range for g? and what is 2.1 in the last line?

Comment: @Wisdom I'm glad I could help. 1. it takes 4.2 seconds on my old laptop. What version of Mathematica are you using? 2. I did not use Brent's method, because that method is an algorithm to find roots. Here you don't want to find a root, but a minimum. So I don't think Brent's method makes sense here. 3. I specified the range of $g$ with the code `1.8 < g < 2.4` (I plotted the function $\Delta$ and determined visually that the minimum was around $g=2$). 4. The 2.1 in the last line is the position of the minimum: $g_\mathrm{min}=2.1$ with $\Delta(g_\mathrm{min})=0.01$.

Comment: Many thanks, 1- you're right, there was some mistype. 2- However in the original paper, the author has mentioned that they have used the Brent's method to find the optimized value of g. Also I read their reference for Brent's method and it was about minimization properly, see the relevant part of this reference: http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Brent_method.pdf
3- Ok, I was curious because the authors also said that they chose a positive range for g at the first.